# which one is correct- "mean" or "meant"?

Tags: grammar

I am not sure about both usages are correct.If both of them are correct, can you clarify the differences.
I couldn't understand what you **mean/meant**.

Comment: Please add examples that confused you so that we know can give a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Mean* is simple present tense.

*Meant* is simple past tense.

In that sentence, *meant* would be correct because *could* is simple past tense.

Answer (score 0):

"Mean" is present tense, while "Meant" is past tense:

> What do you mean by that?    (present tense)
>
> Did you mean .... ?  (present tense)
>
> What he meant to say was ....  (past tense)

Comment: (looks like mik_blom finished typing his answer faster than me :) )

Comment: Your second example isn't a past tense? In the simple past we use the auxiliary verb (did) and the main verb stays on the infinitive, right?